# DDEX provider is not installed for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client error with Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019, oracle-manageddataaccess

After installing visual studio 2019, I tried to update my model in the .edmx file I had this pop-up (I use EntityFrameWork 6 and oracle dataBase)

[image]

Comment: You need an updated version of the Oracle DB support that includes VS2019 support.

Comment: You will need the ODP/Entiy for VS2019, that will be released by Oracle on a future date... The only thing that you can do to use the EDMX is to create/update it on another solution on past releases of visual studio and then paste it in your 2019 solution